# How many k-hyper-cubes does a n-hyper-cube have?

Tags: geometry

Let us say we have an n-dimensional hypercube. How many k-dimensional hypercubes does it contain?

Some observations:

Let us call have a function $S_k(n)$ which returns how many k-cubes are in a n-cube. $$k>n \implies S_k(n)=0$$ $$k=n \implies S_k(n)=1$$ $$k=n-1 \implies S_k(n)=2n$$
$$S_0(n)=2^n$$

Comment: If you look in Wikipedia under hypercube#elements, the formulas are there.